# Common Lisp: unable to load a file into the Lisp interpreter

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Lisp newbie here.

I created a function and put it into this file: compress.lisp

Now I want to load it into the Lisp interpreter that I am using, GCL-2.6.2-ANSI

Here's what I typed into the interpreter:

```
(load "compress.lisp")
```

The interpreter responds with this error:

```
Error in EVAL [or a callee]: Cannot open the file compress.lisp.

Fast links are on: do (use-fast-links nil) for debugging
Broken at CONDITIONS::CLCS-LOAD.  Type :H for Help.
 1 (Continue) Retry loading file "compress.lisp".
 2 (Abort) Return to top level.
dbl:>>
```

Is loading a file not allowed with GCL-2.6.2-ANSI? Or (more likely) I did something incorrect; if so, what?

Comment: can you add the file compres.lisp, maybe the only problem is the path to this file, try to write the complete path to the file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `PROBE-FILE` to check whether there actually is a file under this name in the current directory:

```
CL-USER 57 > (probe-file "compress.lisp") 
NIL
```

Use the function `si:chdir` in GCL to change the current directory to the directory where the file actually is or provide a correct pathname to LOAD.

Comment: Thanks! I tried using the full pathname: (load "C:\Users\costello\Documents\Lisp\compress.lisp") but that resulted in producing this error message: Error in EVAL [or a callee]: Cannot open the file C:UserscostelloDocumentsLispco
mpress.lisp. With regard to your other recommendation, I don't know how to use si:chdir. Do I use it at the Lisp interpreter command line?

Comment: @RogerCostello: \ is a character quoting character in Common Lisp. You have to write "c:\\foo\\bar.com".   if `si:chdir` is a Lisp function, how would you use it? Probably reading the GCL documentation also helps with using it...

Comment: Escaping each backslash in the file path did the trick. (Embarrassed) Yes, reading the GCL documentation is a good idea. Thanks again.